# Multple IP routing on Squid Proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

I have installed Squid Proxy on a server which has 4 IP addresses.eg

- `192.123.0.10`
- `192.123.0.11`
- `192.123.0.12`
- `192.123.0.13`

`192.123.0.10` is the main IP. I want to be able to either:

Set my browser proxy to point to 1 of the four ip's listed and have squid use that correspondining IP as it's outgoing ip address

OR

Set my browser proxy to point to 1 of the four ip's listed and have squid randonmly choose from the outgoing ip from the list

Any ideas?

---

EDIT for clarification:

As an example. Lets say I set my browser to point to `192.123.0.10`, any website I visit should see my IP address as `192.123.0.10`. This works. Then if I change my browser to point to `192.123.0.11`, any website I visit should see my IP address as `192.123.0.11`, but instead it sees the first IP `192.123.0.10`. The same goes for `192.123.0.12` and `192.123.0.13`.

Comment: I don't fully understand your "use that correspondining IP as it's outgoing ip address" bit, could you clarify please.
What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Chopper - I have updated the question with a clarification.

Comment: Can you share more information about your setup?
What is your OS?
Did you setup any extra system configurations like iptables or firewall rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way of doing it. In the squid config I setup 4 http_port values with an acl for each port:

```
acl portA myport 8080
acl portB myport 8081
acl portC myport 8082
acl portD myport 8083
http_port 8080
http_port 8081
http_port 8082
http_port 8083
```

and then I redirect the outgoing ip address according to the port it came in on:

```
tcp_outgoing_address 192.123.0.10 portA
tcp_outgoing_address 192.123.0.11 portB
tcp_outgoing_address 192.123.0.12 portC
tcp_outgoing_address 192.123.0.13 portD
```

Then before I make a request to a certian web page I change the port in the browser proxy settings and the the IP address they see changes.

Only issue is that it seems to have a cache on it. I need to wait a few minutes after I change the proxy port before it reflects the new ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, understand, basically you need to put in a reverse proxy in front of your outgoing proxy ports, creating a four-member VIP with something like sticky round-robin sharing out these IPs between 'clients'.

Comment: So I need an additional server with squid installed?